# How to add cells to a table at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

In my report the number of XRTable cells isn't fixed and depends on data provided each time when a detail band is printed. So, I need to add or remove table cells at runtime. I guess that I should handle the BeforePrint event of the detail band, but without success. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handling the BeforePrint event of the detail band is the best way to add table cells to a table at runtime. But also note that in this case you should use the SuspendLayout and PerformLayout pair of methods to prevent the other table cells in a row being changed. The following example demonstrates how to add an XRTableCell to a table.

```
using DevExpress.XtraReports.UI;

// ...



private void Detail_BeforePrint(object sender, PrintEventArgs e) {

   // Create a new table cell and set its text and width.

   XRTableCell tableCell = new XRTableCell();

   tableCell.Text = "NewCell";

   tableCell.Width = 200;



   // Suspend the table's layout.

   xrTable1.SuspendLayout();



   // Change the table.

   xrTable1.Width = xrTable1.Width + tableCell.Width;

   ((XRTableRow)xrTable1.Rows[0]).Cells.Add(tableCell);



   // Perform the table's layout.

   xrTable1.PerformLayout();

}
```